# iOS - How to download big amount of photos from Flickr

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, fetch, download

I have trouble with downloading amount of photos efficiently from Flickr. I have used off main queue. But it is not enough. Blow is my Code.

```
-(void)flickrNewPhotosFromArray:(NSArray *)photos withCompletionHandler: (void (^) (NSArray*))completionHandler{
    dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("fetch photos1", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{

        NSMutableArray *arrayPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for(int i = 0; i < photos.count; i ++){
            NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSURL *url = [FlickrFetcher URLforPhoto:photos[i] format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
            NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
            NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            CGFloat width = image.size.width;
            CGFloat height = image.size.height;
            [mutableDict setObject:urlString forKey:@"img"];
            [mutableDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:width] forKey:@"w"];
            [mutableDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:height] forKey:@"h"];
            [arrayPhotos addObject:mutableDict];
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (completionHandler) {
                completionHandler(arrayPhotos);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I need to check the width and height of image to meet the requirement of water flow collection view because the dictionary I downloaded doesn't supply these.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: Your last sentence has me confused on what you really want to do. What does the height and width have to do with downloading the actual photos?

Comment: it does not matter, I just explain what I do, Thanks your remind

Comment: What exact issues do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer by myself. Just use group queues to deal with! The answer is below! Still welcome to give me suggestions or supply better answer! Thanks

```
-(void)flickrNewPhotosFromArray:(NSArray *)photos withCompletionHandler: (void (^) (NSArray*))completionHandler{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

        __block NSMutableArray *arrayPhotos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for(int i = 0; i < photos.count; i ++){

            dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                NSURL *url = [FlickrFetcher URLforPhoto:photos[i] format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
                NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
                NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                CGFloat width = image.size.width;
                CGFloat height = image.size.height;
                [mutableDict setObject:urlString forKey:@"img"];
                [mutableDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:width] forKey:@"w"];
                [mutableDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:height] forKey:@"h"];
                [arrayPhotos addObject:mutableDict];

            });
        }
        dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (completionHandler) {
                completionHandler(arrayPhotos);
            }
        });
    });
}
```